# decoding Ascii 7 bits to a readable UTF8 .CSV file

Tags: python, windows, csv, utf-8, decode

I'd like someone to help me with part of my code, there is a problem on the output file that should come out in .csv format using unicode, easy to read on excel. The problem is that the output file comes out without format and the text in it comes in ASCII (7bit).

I really apreaciate your help i've been on this for 4 hours now and can't find the problem yet :/

The last part of the script:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8").replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ").replace("\t",'') for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Python Version is 2.7 on windows 10
is in Ascii

Comment: Which version of python is this?

Comment: Did you forget to write the BOM?

Comment: Is the data you are writting all ascii? ascii and utf-8 look identical if there are no non-ascii chars.

Comment: Python Version is 2.7 on windows 10, and code is in Ascii

Comment: Are you stuck with 2.7 or can you update to 3.x which has much more robust support for unicode? 3.x has been out for many years and if you are having problems with a problem 3.x was specifically designed to fix... then move forward.

Comment: yeah but i've been working on this for a while now, and have already a lot of scripts made on this so i can't really change a this point

Comment: Python 2.7 can easily process utf8 and csv. And I could test your code by feeding it with lists of unicode strings, and it correctly writes an utf8 encoded csv file. Please give a [mcve] with example of use of that class, example input and example output.

Comment: What do you mean by "the output file comes without format"? And why is it a problem that the text is ASCII? As tdelaney pointed out, ASCII and UTF-8 are indistinguishable for characters with code points below 128.

Answer (score 0):

Writing .csv format using unicode, for instance:

```
import io, csv

outfile = 'test/out.csv'
fieldnames = ['field1', 'field2']
content_dict = {'field1':'John', 'field2':'Doo'}

with io.open(outfile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row_dict in content_dict:
        writer.writerow(row_dict)
```